# list exception out of bound

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, pageblocktable

I am getting error as List index out of bound when i try to delete the record from pageblock table.

Sometimes the record gets deleted but sometimes it doesnt. It doesnt perform same everytime.

Following is the code

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbttest"
    value="{!lsttestwrapper}" var="testwrapper">
    <apex:facet name="caption">Test<br />
        <br />
    </apex:facet>

<apex:column value="{!testwrapper.test.First_Name__c}" headerValue="First Name"/>
    <apex:column value="{!testwrapper.test.Surname__c}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
    <apex:column value="{!testwrapper.ident}"
                 rendered="false" />
    <apex:column >
        <apex:commandButton value="Remove"
                            action="{!RemoveTest}"
                            rerender="pbttest ">
            <apex:param name="identity"
                        value="{!testwrapper.ident}"
                        assignTo="{!toDelIdent}" /> 
        </apex:commandButton> 
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlock>
```

Class:

```
public List<signatoryWrapper> lsttestWrapper{get; set;}
    In constructor

    lsttestWrapper= new List<testWrapper>();
    test1=new test__c(); 
public class testWrapper 

      {
        public Integer ident {get; private set;}
        public test__c signtry {get; set;}

        public signatoryWrapper(Integer inIdent,test__c test) 
        {         
            signtry=test;  
            ident=inIdent;   
        }
      }
    public PageReference RemoveTest (){
        PageReference Pageref= null;

        if (lsttestwrapper != null && lsttestwrapper..size() > 0){
            for(testWrapper signw : lsttestwrapper){    
                if(signw.ident == toDelIdent){                  
                    test__c test = [    SELECT  Id 
                                        FROM    Test__c 
                                        WHERE   Id =:signw.signtry.id limit 1]; 
                    delete test;
                }
            }
            // Deletion successful?
            if(lsttestwrapper.size()>0){
                lsttestwrapper.remove(toDelIdent);
            }
         }
        return Pageref;
    }
```

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 2

Comment: What row does your exception happen on? If you post the entire error message we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Is lsttestwrapper a List? Or is it a Map? I am also worried about the two dots within the if statement. It tells us that this is not exactly the code that is running in your org.

Comment: You would also need to bulkify your code, having a SOQL query inside a for loop could easily hit the governor limits

Comment: @Prady it will only run once for the entry with the Id to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I make a guess here:

I assume lsttestwrapper is a List (Otherwise the for loop wouldn't make sense). If the list contains two entries, e.g. with Ids 2 and 3, and toDelInt is 2 it will happily delete the record with Id 2 and subsequently try to remove the entry #2 from the two-element list - which  only has entries #0 and #1.

You're mixing record Ids with list entry indexes.

Also, why is the "Deletion successful?" part not within the innermost if branch? Would make more sense if you ask me.

Comment: Have edited the question to include all the code.. please have a look at it

Comment: @TestNS: So there's your problem: "lsttestwrapper.remove(toDelIdent);" with toDelIdent being a record Id. See [List.remove](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_List_remove.htm) for more details.

Comment: @FrankZ.. toDelIdent is an integer value and not record Id.

Comment: @TestNS You're right, my fault. Can you confirm that toDelInt is an index (not a key!) in the List lsttestwrapper? I mean, do you ensure that toDelInt is always >= 0 and < lsttestwrapper.size()

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:
List of the size is less than the value of "toDelIdent".

```
if(lsttestwrapper.size()>0){

       lsttestwrapper.remove(toDelIdent);
 }
```

You can fix it like this:

```
if(lsttestwrapper.size()>toDelIdent){

        lsttestwrapper.remove(toDelIdent);
    }
```